# connect cat5e and telephone wire 22/4c

Tags: networking, modem, cable, cat5e

I need help. I'm not really good at networking. I have this telephone line that's connected to my router. It's a 22/4c as it is labeled on the wire. Now my pet hamsters escaped and was chewing off the cover of of my telephone wire and now I got no internet connection. I have a spare cat5e cable, now my question is can I connect a 22/4c wire to a cat5e utp cable?

Comment: Although you can splice it with any old copper, you will be introducing much noise into the line.  Replace it as soon as you can.

Comment: @Josh -- The Cat5 is better than the original phone cable, in terms of noise rejection.  It's often used for new phone installations, so that only one type of cable is needed.

Comment: @DanielRHicks of course, my point is that the instant you interrupt the twist, you have yourself an antennae.  Splice, yes, but replace asap.

Comment: @Josh -- Actually, standard phone company cable isn't twisted, or is twisted very "lazily".  The Cat5 is intensely twisted, but untwisting it to splice will not make it any worse than standard phone cable.

Comment: @DanielRHicks- there is no standard.  50 different houses will have 25 different "standards".  All I'm saying is that in my experience, anything other than an unblemished cable is asking for it.  Cut it up, splice it, that's fine, and it likely won't even make a difference with voice, but I would not want a bare copper splice in the source of my internet connection.  Worse than standard phone cable is a low bar imho.

Comment: @Josh -- I've been mucking around with phone systems since the 50s, have a masters in EE, have been employed in the computer biz over 40 years.  I think my experience trumps yours.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6283/discussion-between-josh-and-daniel-r-hicks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splice the wires, making sure that whatever wire in the new piece is connected to a color on one end is connected to the same color on the other end.  Leave plenty of slack.

How you splice is up to you -- for short term you can just twist the "stripped" (insulation removed) wires together tightly and wrap with some sort of tape (but such a splice will pull apart easily).  For a robust connection you should use a connection block or crimp connectors and anchor the cables on either side so they won't be pulled loose.

(Cat 5 is used in place of phone cable all the time, so the cable is up to the task.)

(PS: With no internet connection, how did you post the above and how will you read this?)

Comment: thats a good question actually. Maybe its different here but wouldn't the connectors be different?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek -- Well, if you're splicing you don't care about the connectors.  But you can, if you wish, get a RJ-45 to screw terminal connector block so you can use the connector on the Cat5.

Comment: yes thank you, this is exactly what i did and now it works better than the old telephone line..i connected the orange and brown wire in the cat5e cable to the adsl splitter and it worked. :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could just patch up your old cable?

some soldering or a luster terminal could solve your issue for now, until you get this cable replaced.

[image: luster terminal]

Just remove some of the isolation and connect the wires by color.

Comment: What's a 'luster terminal'?

Comment: these thingies: http://www.stockpodium.com/stock-photo-8851754/luster-terminal-image.jpg

Comment: That'd be a screw terminal block.  Probably better/simpler are crimp connectors.

Comment: sorry, dict.cc failed me ^^ - however, I don't like crimp connectors that much in these cases, because: you need the right sice and preferably the right tool to crimp them, otherwise its a bit messy and unreliable - a screw terminal would be easier to find & to handle

Comment: There are rather nice little crimp connectors for phone lines that only require pliers and are about as secure and reliable as one could want.  After all, the phone company has used them for about 40 years.  Screw terminals are in my (considerable) experience less reliable -- the wires (unless field tinned) often go "haywire" and short out or pull loose.